# Add attributes to class & properties on the fly

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

Is there anything in castle that can let me add attributes to a class on the fly?

I have a dto in a project that I want to use as a data contract in a wcf service. I'd need to add a

```
[DataContract]
```

attribute to the class and then

```
[DataMember]
```

to each of the properties.

I could just replicate the class in the service layer and then copy the list to a new list of the new type but thats a ballache. There must be something in dynamicproxy or somewhere?

w://

Comment: Aren't those different layers?

Comment: Just seems a bit silly replicating the code in the service layer, just to add a couple of attributes to a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not out of the box
2. WCF 3.5 or newer does not require attributes on data contracts.